# Double dispatch in R: S4 vs vctrs library

Tags: r, r-s4, double-dispatch, multiple-dispatch, vctrs

If we want to implement a double dispatch method in R, we currently have two options to choose from:

- S4 methods
- vctrs library [S3-based double dispatch](https://yutani.rbind.io/post/double-dispatch-of-s3-method/)

I especially mean arithmetic operators, such as + or *.

How do they compare in terms of performance?
Are their overheads comparable?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and you could probably make it on-topic with an example of the type of problem you are attempting to solve, but in its current format it invites only comment and opinion. For that reason I feel compelled to vote to close. I will happily retract this if you turn it into a question that could have a factual answer.